# RivetsJS update model with a save function

Tags: jquery, data-binding, rivets

Ive got these inputs and if i use rv-value i can update the data real time but i want to parse the data only if a user clicks save .. how can i do this?

```
    <form class="form">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label>ID</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="id" value="" rv-placeholder="user.id" rv-value=""><br/>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="name" value="" rv-placeholder="user.name" rv-value=""><br/>
            <label>Age</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="age" value="" rv-placeholder="user.age" rv-value="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label>City</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="city" value="" rv-placeholder="user.city" rv-value="user.city"><br/>
            <label>State</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="state" value="" rv-placeholder="user.state" rv-value=""><br/>
            <label>Zip</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="zip" value="" rv-placeholder="user.zip" rv-value="">
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a fiddle which answers your question: https://jsfiddle.net/fba88ph9/13/

```
var data = {
    placeholder: {
    id: 0,
    name: "your name",
    age: "your age",
    city: "city",
    state: "state",
    zip: "1804YZ"
  },
  user : {},
  save : function(){
    var parsedData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.user));
    //do something with the parsedData.
    console.log(parsedData);
  }
};


rivets.bind($("#app"), data);
```

I have separated the user object and the placeholder object. By binding the user keys to `rv-value`, the user object will be updated whenever you change the form. The added save button will call the save function when pressed by using `rv-on-click`. This will clone the current data with a JSON parse trick.